# Is there something like onclick/onfocus for tabhost/tabspec?

Tags: android, android-tabhost

I've a fully working tabhost/tabspec app (first working self-made app ever :D) see code beneath.
Now, the following: when tab NORM is pressed I want to run a few lines of code. Is there something like an onclick for the tabhost/tabspec. Any help appreciated

```
public class AndroidTabLayoutActivity extends TabActivity {

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();

    // Tab for Dag
    TabSpec dagspec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Dag");
    dagspec.setIndicator("DagRooster", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_dag_tab));
    Intent dagIntent = new Intent(this, DagActivity.class);
    dagspec.setContent(dagIntent);


    // Tab for Norm
    TabSpec normspec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Norm");
    // setting Title and Icon for the Tab
    normspec.setIndicator("Normaal", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_norm_tab));
    Intent normIntent = new Intent(this, NormActivity.class);
    normspec.setContent(normIntent);


    // Tab for Instel
    TabSpec instelspec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Instel");
    instelspec.setIndicator("Info", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_setting_tab));
    Intent instelIntent = new Intent(this, InstelActivity.class);
     instelspec.setContent(instelIntent);


    // Adding all TabSpec to TabHost
    tabHost.addTab(dagspec); // Adding photos tab
    tabHost.addTab(normspec); // Adding songs tab
    tabHost.addTab(instelspec); // Adding videos tab
    tabHost.setCurrentTab(2);

        }
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add TabHost to OnTabChangeListener() like this:

```
// Exit Application when press Exit tab
    tabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(new TabHost.OnTabChangeListener() {     
        @Override
        public void onTabChanged(String arg0) {
            if (getTabHost().getCurrentTabTag().equals("Exit")){
                finish();                   
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can use

```
tabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(new OnTabChangeListener() {
   @Override
  public void onTabChanged(String arg0) {
   Log.i("param1", "param2" + tabHost.getCurrentTab());
  }     
       });
```

or

You may use the approach discussed in this [SO discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1062476/onclicklistener-on-tabs-not-working).

Comment: When I add your code I get the following error: The method setOnTabChangedListener(TabHost.OnTabChangeListener) in the type TabHost is not applicable for the arguments (new OnTabChangeListener(){})